# Package.appxmanifest conditional or include

Tags: uwp, manifest, appx, appxmanifest

I have an app with background tasks that I want registered or not based on a build time variable. I know that in a .csproj file I can use Condition in the  to specify the manifest to use. The problem with this is that most of the contents of the two manifests are identical. Can I either (a) somehow use a condition in a single manifest instead, or (b) factor out the common elements and somehow include them into two otherwise minimal manifests? I didn't find a way to do either, resulting in duplication which is obviously bad.

Comment: I'm confused about why you have two manifests? And what is the Condition you mentioned to specify the manifest to use? Can you show more details about the Condition or code snippet?

Comment: Well to declare a background task you have to put it in the appxmanifest as <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="Tasks.FooTask">...
I need that declaration to be conditional on a define constant. Right now we have two manifests and the build server uses one or the other based on a constant; this is quite awful because it duplicates all the other stuff in the manifests.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to control when background tasks are registered via controlling the declarations in the manifest? If it is, you need to control the registration of background tasks with code instead of through declarations in the manifest.

Comment: I thought it's not possible to register it's not declared in the manifest with <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint=.....
Referring to Windows Store app specifically.

Comment: Yes, if you don't declare the background task in the app manifest, you can't run background tasks successfully, so you need to declare it in the manifest. But about when to register background tasks, it should be controlled by when you use BackgroundTaskBuilder.Register() method after you declare in the manifest.

Comment: Well my goal is to have builds conditionally include or exclude the assemblies for the background task classes and not even build them based on build configuration setting such as an environment variable. But how do I avoid duplication of the manifest if I can't use a conditional in the manifest or have two manifests that include the common stuff?

Comment: We have never seen the practice of two manifests, and we cannot guarantee whether this approach is reasonable.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT: Well, take a look at Windows Terminal, then: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/fc7b052461cd7c513b3a057a10ae88d9e83dfbc8/src/cascadia/CascadiaPackage/CascadiaPackage.wapproj#L38-L48

Comment: @SamB if you add this as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

We do this with two appxmanifest files as seen in [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/fc7b052461cd7c513b3a057a10ae88d9e83dfbc8/src/cascadia/CascadiaPackage/CascadiaPackage.wapproj#L38-L48).

```
    <AppxManifest Include="Package.appxmanifest" Condition="'$(Configuration)'!='Debug'" SubType="Designer"/>
    <AppxManifest Include="Package-DEBUG.appxmanifest" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'" SubType="Designer"/>
```